# Can you split ammunition stacks in Resident Evil 7?

Tags: resident-evil-7

On my second playthrough I easily reached the ammo cap for both pistol and shotgun (30). Is it possible to split stacks, for instance taking out 10 shots and storing them in the item box?

The inventory space is limited even after the backpack upgrade (+4 slots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible for ammo. However, it's possible for other items.

According to [official game manual](http://game.capcom.com/manual/re7/en/windows/page/4/2) one can store into item box single item from the stack. So you can use this function on your ammo stacks repeatatly until desired amount remains in your inventory.

Tests show, this works for gunpowder, solid fuel.

Comment: Sorry, I confused "supply chest" with the item box.

Comment: @user238464 this is how it's called in official manual, but we players can call it whatever we want :)

Comment: "Supply box" is a pre-order bonus item, hence the term should be avoided.

Comment: Unfortunately after testing with most items, the ←/→ icon doesn't appear for ammo types when moving items to or out of the inventory. Only available for ammo-related crafting items (gunpowder, solid fuel) and rest of the items which stack. Your answer is still worthwhile since you referred to the game manual, you only have to edit accordingly.

Comment: @user238464 that's unfortunate, I've edited it now, once I get home will tests with other items